# Is it possible to get request data from javax.ws.rs.core.Response?

Tags: java, jersey, client

I use jersey **client** v2 with builder api. It returns response object:

```
Response response = client
                .target(uri)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .put(Entity.json("{}"))
```

I wanna log incorrect requests:
 `log.warn("Incorrect request by url {} - {}", response.???, response.getStatus())`.

Is it possible to get request data from response object?

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible to get request data from javax.ws.rs.core.Response if and only if you hit proper URL. then it will go into you service method.

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
public Response test(@Context HttpContext context) {
    context.getRequest(); //get request metadata 
}
```

But if you are hitting a URL which is not defined then you wont get control in service method.

Comment: please note that I'm talking about jersey **client** api (to make http requests).